# FTP LIST file error: 425 Unable to build data connection: TLS session of data connection not resumed

Tags: java, spring-boot, ftp, tls1.2, apache-commons-net

I'm trying to connect to a FTPS Server using commons-net lib FTPSClient in a SpringBoot Application.
I'm able to connect, login and change the directory using FTPSClient from commons-net lib. But as soon as I'm trying to list the file, it says "**425 Unable to build data connection: TLS session of data connection not resumed.**"
From what I know, the FTP Server were recently updated to only accept TLS Version 1.2 and above. I also tried to set the TLS Version, override "*prepareDataSocket*" method in FTPSClient, etc. But the same error "**425 Unable to build data connection: TLS session of data connection not resumed.**" still throws.
And I can list the files if I use the FileZilla application to access the FTPS Server, but not my Java code with commons-net library. I'm not sure why it happened.

The following is are code for connecting, login, and trying to list the files from FTPS Server.

```
System.setProperty("jdk.tls.client.protocols", "TLSv1.2,TLSv1.3");
FTPSClient ftp = new FTPSClient();

//Socket Opening TimeoutÏ
ftp.setDefaultTimeout(time10mins);
//Data Reading Timeout
ftp.setDataTimeout(time30mins);
//Connection Timeout
ftp.setConnectTimeout(time10mins);

String[] tlsVersions = {"TLSv1.2", "TLSv1.3"};
ftp.setEnabledProtocols(tlsVersions);
ftp.addProtocolCommandListener(new PrintCommandListener(new PrintWriter(System.out), true));
ftp.connect(ftpProperties.getFtpHost(), ftpProperties.getFtpPort());
ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();
int reply = ftp.getReplyCode();
if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)) {
  ftp.disconnect();
  throw new IOException("Exception in connecting to FTP Server");
}
//Socket Timeout after opening connection
ftp.setSoTimeout(time30mins);
ftp.login(ftpProperties.getFtpUsername(), ftpProperties.getFtpPassword());

ftp.execPROT("P");
ftp.execPBSZ(0);
ftp.type(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

LOGGER.info("Connected to FTP location");

FileOutputStream fos;
LOGGER.info("Downloading files for " + today);

//Download Category Mapping files
ftp.changeWorkingDirectory(ftpProperties.getFtpDirectory());
FTPFile[] files = ftp.listFiles();
LOGGER.info("files length: " + files.length);
```

And the following are the logs that I can see:

```
`250 CWD command successful

SYST

215 UNIX emulated by FileZilla.

PASV

227 Entering Passive Mode

LIST

150 Starting data transfer.

425 Unable to build data connection: TLS session of data connection not resumed.`
```

As we can see, we can connection, login, and change the directory but LIST files failed. And I can even see "**150 Starting data transfer**" but still I get "**TLS session of data connection not resumed.**" error.
I also couldn't figure out why I can list the files if I use the FileZilla desktop to access the FTPS Server, but not the Java code.
Thank you for your help!